# Can i fake having a gyroscope?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sensors, gyroscope

I recently started playing 'Pokémon Go', but for the AR/VR to work a gyroscope is required.
Is it possible to simulate/fake a gyroscope using the sensors already in the phone?

I have a Vodafone smart 6 Ultra running Android 5.0.2
Sensors:

- Accelerometer
- Magnetometer
- Gravity Sensor
- Linear Acceleration
- Rotation Sensor
- Proximity Sensor
- Light Sensor

I have tried searching for a solution, but google only brings up others looking for an attachment which acts as the gyroscope.
I also tried searching for the specific issue within the game, but that had nothing either.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but it requires extensive android development knowledge, rooting your phone (which i do not condone and do not take responsibility for any errors that occur if you choose to do it). This isn't even simple rooting either. You'd need to know how use XPosed, and the module for it isn't even complete either. Even if you did manage to fake a gyroscope, using other sensor data, it would still come out as lackluster, and ruin your pokemon go experience. hope that helps.

sources: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/app-request-gyroscope-emulator-virtual-t3186938